# PHP NGINX not working on a Subdomain

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, subdomain, home-directory, public-folders

I have a Sub Domain"

ad.example.com   and I am trying to install a CMS and it get stuck at install.php with a 404 not Found error

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ad.example.com.access.log;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/ad.example.com.error.log;

    listen 8000;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  ad.example.com;
    root   /usr/local/www/ad.example.com/html;


    location / {
       index  index.php index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
         
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         
         fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index  index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Although i can check ad.example.com/info.php   it works
but  ad.example.com/www/admin/info.php  does not work
ad.example.com/www/admin/install.php    404 Error Not Found

Comment: Where are your CMS files?

Comment: CMS FIles are in the HTML Folder but the install.php is in the Admin Folder. so the path that is generated is html/www/admin/install.php.. i reconfigured the root to /...../html/www/admin but still the same error

Comment: Just to confirm, CMS files are in `/usr/local/www/ad.example.com/html` and admin folder is at `/usr/local/www/ad.example.com/html/www/admin`?

Comment: yes I confirm CMS files are in /usr/local/www/ad.example.com/html and admin folder is at /usr/local/www/ad.example.com/html/www/admin

Comment: Anybody can help?

Comment: Issue Resolved, Changed the default server back to port 80